# Using predict for more complicated predictions

Tags: r, data.table, glm, predict

I'm a bit lost on whether there's a simpler way to use `predict` to get out predictions from more complicated regression frameworks.

Take, for example, the following:

```
NN<-1e4
data<-data.table(trt=sample(paste("Treatment",1:3),NN,T),
                 qtl=sample(paste0("Q",1:2),NN,T),
                 grp=sample(4,NN,T),
                 cat=sample(paste("Category",LETTERS[1:3]),NN,T),
                 val=rnorm(NN,10)^2)

data[,out:=140+5*(trt=="Treatment 2")+3*(trt=="Treatment 3")+
       8*(qtl=="Q2")-4*(trt=="Treatment 2"&qtl=="Q2")+
       7*(trt=="Treatment 3"&qtl=="Q2")-4*(grp==2)+
       6*(grp==3)-10*(grp==4)-6*(cat=="Category B")+
       2*(cat=="Category C")-1.8*val+rnorm(NN,10)>0]

llog<-glm(out~trt*qtl+as.factor(grp)+cat+val,data=data,family=binomial(link="logit"))
```

Now, I want to get out of this predictions for the probability that `out`=1 *by `trt`*, *by `qtl`*, with **all other predictors held at sample averages**.

Let's say I want this, for this case, in a 3 x 2 matrix (or table, etc.) with rows corresponding to `trt`, columns to `qtl`

This is complicated in particular by the presence of factor variables--"held at sample averages" means we need to plug in the percentage of observations in each group, and I'm not sure how to do so in a clean way.

The really long way to do this, of course, is the following:

1) set up a vector of sample averages for the "other predictors":

```
oth.avg<-c(1,unlist(data[,lapply(list(grp==2,grp==3,grp==4,cat=="Category B",
                                  cat=="Category C",val),mean)]))
```

2) multiply with the corresponding coefficients

```
x.beta.oth<-sum(llog$coefficients[c(1,5:10)]*oth.avg)
```

3) set up "matrices" for `trt`, `qtl` and `trt`x`qtl` terms:
     (I say "matrices" because they're conceptually drawn from
      underlying matrices, but it's more concise to specify them
      in one dimension)

```
main.coef<-llog$coefficients[c(2:4,11:12)]
trt.mat<-rep(c(0,main.coef[1:2]),2)
qtl.mat<-rep(c(0,main.coef[3]),each=3)
tq.mat<-c(rep(0,3),rbind(rep(0,1),matrix(main.coef[4:5],ncol=1)))
```

(it's overkill to specify them like this in this small example, but the parsimony starts to show itself when the table is, say, 4x4.

4) add everything to get the predicted latent index

```
lat.pred<-trt.mat+qtl.mat+tq.mat+x.beta.oth
```

5) finally, transform these into predicted probabilities via the logistic formula: p/(1+p)

```
pred.prob<-matrix(exp(lat.pred)/(1+exp(lat.pred)),ncol=2,
              dimnames=list(paste("Treatment",1:3),c("Q1","Q2")))

                      Q1           Q2
Treatment 1 3.515452e-28 6.000161e-22
Treatment 2 1.989195e-24 1.519577e-27
Treatment 3 3.380796e-26 1.633097e-20
```

Am I missing something? I don't see what I could feed into `predict` to get this output...

Comment: I might be completely mistaken, but the probabilities seem hard to interpret at sample averages of group and category (as these will not occur in reality). Could you use the most prevalent factor for group and category in a newdata-dataframe that you feed to predict? Furthermore, your 'grp'-variable is used as continuous in your example model, while it seems you intended a factor.

Comment: sorry, that's a typo; fixed

Comment: and i agree it's a bit strange (though your alternative is not great either), and perhaps I should post the statistics side of this on cross validated; i posted it here to focus on the programming side more than the statistics/interpretation side

Comment: I agree with @Heroka; it's difficult to understand quite what it would mean being at the average of groups. One possibility would be to take all of the possible combinations of group/category and the average val, feed them all to predict as the new.data and take an average result (weighted if felt appropriate by the proportions in the original data). I think it would be sensible to sort out whether what you're proposing is statistically valid before addressing the programming.

Comment: My reasoning for using this is that if you just take the average of all the indicators for each group, it becomes the probability of being in that group. Anyway, I've taken your advice and posted this question on [CV](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157942/common-approaches-to-illustrating-central-responsiveness-in-linear-regression).

Comment: As seen on the [CV post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157942/common-approaches-to-illustrating-central-responsiveness-in-linear-regression), statistics people (at least so far) seem to agree with my approach. Back to trying to implement it in `R`; any suggestions?